# Splitting before tfidf or after?

Tags: machine-learning, python, nlp, preprocessing, data-leakage

When should I perform preprocessing and matrix creation of text data in NLP, before or after `train_test_split`? Below is my sample code where I have done preprocessing and matrix creation (tfidf) before `train_test_split`. I want to know will there be data leakage?

```
corpus = []

for i in range(0 ,len(data1)):
    review = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]', ' ', data1['features'][i])
    review = review.lower()
    review = review.split()
    review = [stemmer.stem(j) for j in review if not j in set(stopwords.words('english'))]
    review = ' '.join(review)
    corpus.append(review)

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
cv = TfidfVectorizer(max_features = 6000)
x = cv.fit_transform(corpus).toarray()

from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
le = LabelEncoder()
y = le.fit_transform(data1['label'])

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
train_x, test_x, train_y, test_y = train_test_split(x, y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 69, 
                                                                                stratify = y)

spam_model = MultinomialNB().fit(train_x, train_y)
pred = spam_model.predict(test_x)
c_matrix = confusion_matrix(test_y, pred)
acc_score = accuracy_score(test_y, pred)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should split **before** tf-idf.

If you learn tf-idf also on the test set you will have data leakage. In example, you won't have out-of-vocabulary words in inference on the test set, what might happen in the "real world".

Comment: Ok how about the preprocessing of text (like lemmatization, removing stopwords, lowercase etc)? Should I do that before or after the split?

Comment: I don't see a difference because those are fixed procedures, they are not data based.

Comment: Lemmatization is data based

Comment: Also can you provide me with an example where Vectorization is done after splitting data? Because eveywhere I looked, they perform Vectorization before splitting.

Comment: The lemmatization I know is not learned.

Comment: You can take as an example every real life project in which you don't have access to the real time data when training your model.

Comment: Actually I have searched for example where vectorization is done after splitting but couldn't find one. Everywhere they perform vectorization before splitting which as you pointed out will lead to data leakage. Do you have any links where it is done after splitting?